# Google Hangouts crashes my Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, firefox, software-center, google-chrome, google-hangouts

I'm having some difficulty with Google Hangouts right now. Most of the time (it's unpredictable), when I go to call or recieve a call, it starts to play the ringtone, and then freezes. I cannot open any other windows (like Terminal). I'm using Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04. I have i3wm installed, but the problem persists whether or not I'm using my native window manager. My first instinct was to check / uncheck the "enabled" button beside the google hangouts app, but nothing changed.
I've also tried Firefox, with a different but not better result. When I go to click to join the call, I get prompted to download the google hangouts plugin. However, after doing this, when I go to join the call again, it still wants me to install the hangouts plugin. Also, Software Center never says "uninstall" or "reinstall" but simply "install" after I've *already* installed it. I take that as a sign that the installation actually didn't happen.
Any ideas on what's going on or how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

P.S. This has worked reliably in the past. I think it is since I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04 that these problems have emerged.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you install [the Hangouts Plugin](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/hangoutplugin) that wont be a big problem any more.

This similar question might be helpful: [My Google Hangouts is crashing on a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 on LightDM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674472/my-google-hangouts-is-crashing-on-a-fresh-install-of-ubuntu-14-04-on-lightdm?rq=1)

Comment: it's an extension for google chrome .

Comment: search about it in google extensions ,
i think it will help because it helped me when i had had problems with hangouts

Comment: ooh it was Hangouts plugin not extension .. i'll edit the answer

Comment: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/hangoutplugin

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding details... but seems like OP already installed the plugin... and the linked post looks quite specific